# How to pass specific log file from filebeat to logstash and where does logstash store these log files?

Tags: elastic-stack

I have ELk 6.4 setup in centos 7 and installed filebeat in one server where my nginx server is running. I copied a log file from another server of previous date and how to pass this log file to logstash. I am unable to find the logs in kibana. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Configure filebeat to look at your log files. Specify the log file path.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html

Configure filebeat output to point to Logstash host and port.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html